# How Can I Implement somthing like delegate(c#) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, delegates

I want to have a delegate of a function in javascript is it posible have something like delegate concept like c# in javascript?

Comment: You can assign functions to variables, nuff said

Comment: When you're tagging, you should answer "_my question is about ..._". Obviously your question is not about c#.

Comment: If you are in need of multicast delegates (e.g. like c# events) maybe check out [jquery callbacks](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Callbacks/)

Answer (score 1):

They're called `function expressions`

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions for a lengthy discourse

```
const square = function(number) { return number * number }
var x = square(4) // x gets the value 16
```